# neo4j counting unique edges

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm a newbie so I apologize for the simple question but I seem to be approaching this the wrong way, there has to be a much simpler way in Cypher.

I have a simple network such as:

```
(n)-[r:Knows]->(m)
```

I need to know the number of edges between n and m but if there are multiple edgers I need to count it as 1 as essentially I need to know if the edge exist or not.

What's the best way to to do this?

Comment: Do you want edges between `(n)` and `(m)` or paths? Edge is referring you want a single edge. But also you are looking for multiple edges. Usually you only have one edge `:KNOWS` between two nodes. And it feels like you are looking for paths (multiple or a single edge).

Comment: yes sorry about the lack of terminology, the paths are what I'm looking for.  I would like to count the number of unique paths between the two nodes.  The way the relationship was created leads to the fact that multiple paths are there but I only need to count one.  Even if count(r) > 1 I still need to count just one.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use the `exists()` function, which can check for the existence of a pattern.

```
...
WITH exists((n)-[:Knows*]->(m)) as existsConnection
...
```